# Lost ActionBar title when add custom back button

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

All- I added a custom back button in my ActionBar Sherlock to fit my orange theme:
[image]
The problem is doing so made the title disappear. This is how it should look plus the carrot:
[image]

I also changed the icon but I narrowed the problem down to the carrot not the icon. Anybody got this problem also and is so a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just by moving on to my next task I stumbled upon my answer by chance. For those of you that might have the same problem here is your answer:

```
   <style parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid" name="example_solid_ActionBar">  
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo|showTitle</item> 
//...
</style>
```